# Array of objects empty in Android, but not in iOS

Tags: react-native

I am building an app in react native that uses Auth0 for user authentication. I also use Auth0 to pull down an array of data from the user's metadata(JSON).

The app works perfectly in iOS, but in Android the array in the user's metadata is empty. Everything besides the array loads properly.

After testing, I have realized that the problem only occurs if the array is an array of objects. If I change it to an array of test strings, the array loads in Android.

Does anyone know why an array of objects in JSON data would load in iOS but not in Android?

Answer (score 0):

Are you using the latest version of **react native**???

Answer (score 0):

I spoke to Auth0 about this, and they created this ticket: https://github.com/auth0/react-native-lock/issues/138

Looks like it wasn't anything I did wrong. Those are the worst :/